# Explaining the logic behind the pipe_line method for cross-validation of imbalance datasets

Tags: class-imbalance, pipelines, imbalanced-learn, methodology, oversampling

Reading the following article: https://kiwidamien.github.io/how-to-do-cross-validation-when-upsampling-data.html

There is an explanation of how to use `from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline` in order to perform a cross-validation on an imbalanced dataset while avoiding memory leakage.

Here I copy the code used in the notebook linked by the article:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=45)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=13)


imba_pipeline = make_pipeline(SMOTE(random_state=42), 
                              RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=13))
cross_val_score(imba_pipeline, X_train, y_train, scoring='recall', cv=kf)

new_params = {'randomforestclassifier__' + key: params[key] for key in params}
grid_imba = GridSearchCV(imba_pipeline, param_grid=new_params, cv=kf, scoring='recall',
                         return_train_score=True)
grid_imba.fit(X_train, y_train);

grid_imba.best_params_
grid_imba.best_score_
```

I do not understand why using the pipeline avoids the problem of building a validation set that, due to a possible oversampling *before* splitting, might cause memory leakage problems.

Secondy, can we use the pipeline for the same purpose but using the original data-set "X,y" as parameters for the arguments of the functions in the pipeline? So in this way:

```
imba_pipeline = make_pipeline(SMOTE(random_state=42), 
                              RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=13))
cross_val_score(imba_pipeline, X, y, scoring='recall', cv=kf)

new_params = {'randomforestclassifier__' + key: params[key] for key in params}
grid_imba = GridSearchCV(imba_pipeline, param_grid=new_params, cv=kf, scoring='recall',
                         return_train_score=True)
grid_imba.fit(X, y);

grid_imba.best_params_
grid_imba.best_score_
```

Answer (score 1):

The page linked already gives a really good explanation:

> To see why this is an issue, consider the simplest method of
> over-sampling (namely, copying the data point). Let's say every data
> point from the minority class is copied 6 times before making the
> splits. If we did a 3-fold validation, each fold has (on average) 2
> copies of each point! If our classifier overfits by memorizing its
> training set, it should be able to get a perfect score on the
> validation set! Our cross-validation will choose the model that
> overfits the most. We see that CV chose the deepest trees it could!

The main point is that you need to make sure that the data is first split into train/test by using the cross-validation before applying any upsampling methods. This can be achieved by using a pipeline since it makes sure that the upsampling and model fitting are combined and are applied only after the data is split for cross-validation. It would still be possible to do this without a pipeline by splitting the two steps and applying them manually but you'd have to do the cross-validation splitting yourself by using a using indices from [`sklearn.model_selection.KFold`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) (see the example provided) since `cross_val_score` and `GridSearchCV` have no option for this and only allow a single estimator (which itself can also be a pipeline of multiple steps).

Comment: Thansk, now it is more clear. I just wanted to ask an additional thing: which metho in the pipeline assures us that training set and validation set are upsampled after the split?

Comment: This is just the way the `cross_val_score` and `GridSearchCV` work, they first split the data based on the cross-validation method and then apply the estimator. Since the estimator in this case is a pipeline of both the upsampling and model this will only be applied after the cross-validation split.